# heroku ssl endpoint - http vs https

Tags: ssl, heroku

I've setup 'ssl endpoint' on heroku and that works great.  I have a cname for www.miketown3.com pointing to osaka-4635.herokussl.com.  https is working great.

However, when I GET http://www.miketown3.com, I get redirected to https://www.miketown3.com and I want to remain on http.  When testing my app locally this does not happen.  Also, when watching the traffic in chrome, I see no http level redirection of any kind.  There's just a request to http://www.miketown3.com with no response.  Then immediately the next request is to https://www.miketown3.com, but this time there is a valid response.

My question, where is this redirection happening and how can I stop it?  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a chrome cache thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since your www subdomain is pointed to osaka-4635.herokussl.com, the server at this address performs the redirection. To stop it, you have to remove the ssl endpoint addon, and change your DNS records per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains (e.g. point your root and www subdomain to yourapp.herokuapp.com)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you question is but if you only want HTTPS for certain parts(urls) of your website and assuming you are using rails you can add the gem `'rack-ssl-enforcer'`, this will allow you to specify what parts of your website redirect to https i.e. login